# Aluminum Alloy Wheel Scratch Repair

Tags: wheels, suzuki

I have a copper 2011 Suzuki SX4 Crossover.  I bought it in May, and I accidentally put a pretty big scratch on one of the aluminum alloy wheels the other day when I hit the curb.  Can this be repaired easily?  Is there a way that I can buff or polish it out?  The simpler the better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a guy that would come in and do magin on BMW wheels for $50. He used what I can only compare to bondo, and then painted the wheel. Looked as if nothing ever happened. I would check with and auto parts store to see if they sell anything like this, if not you can probably call a dealer see if they know someone.